# Powershell : This operation returned because the timeout period expiredAt

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to run `xTestPlan_1.ps1` from `enable_local.ps1`.

While `enable_local.ps1` is on my local machine, `xTestPlan_1.ps1` is on network drive. I only have the shortcut to `xTestPlan_1.ps1` on my local machine.

Here is `enable_local.ps1`:

```
$item = "d:\temp\xTestPlan_1.lnk"
WriteInLogFile "$item"
Try
{
    & "$item"
}
Catch
{
    WriteInLogFile $Error
}
```

While running this code, sometimes, I get this error:

> Program "xTestPlan_1.lnk" failed to run: This operation returned
>   because the timeout period expired At D:\Temp\enable_local.ps1.

This script sometimes works as expected, sometimes it does not work. `xTestPlan_1.ps1` does exist on the network drive.

Comment: Does "sometimes, I get this error" mean that sometimes it works as expected?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. yes, it means, some times it works fine and sometimes it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to execute a shortcut isn't a good way to run another script.

A better to do this is to call the script directly:

```
$item = "\\server\share\xTestPlan_1.ps1"
WriteInLogFile "$item"
Try
{
    & $item
}
Catch
{
    WriteInLogFile $Error
}
```

If you really must use a shortcut for some reason, you can get the target path from the shortcut and then call the script itself.

```
$item = "d:\temp\xTestPlan_1.lnk"

$ShellObj = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
$targetPath = $ShellObj.CreateShortcut($item).TargetPath

WriteInLogFile "$targetPath"
Try
{
    & $targetPath
}
Catch
{
    WriteInLogFile $Error
}
```